# The hard typed number turns out to be string in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

*Disclaimer. Please note that it's not a question about why 1 and '1' in JavaScript differ. It's not a question about the difference between `==` and `===`. And it's not a question about how to compare 1 and '1'.*

I have the code below.

```
test(input: number) {
  let index = 5;
  console.log(typeof (index) + " " + typeof (input));
  console.log(index === input);
}
```

The first line prints *number string* and, of course, the second is *false*. I can't for the life of me understand it. Googling for 20 minutes - I only see examples showing that reception of the parameter is hard typed and should be a number.

What am I missing?

Comment: `let index = 5` is different than `num: number = 5`

Comment: Well how are you *calling* the function?

Comment: @Pointy It's getting an ID from a DOM element. My surprise is that it's a string even though I say I want the parameter to be number...

Comment: Typings are not enforced at runtime. You are most likely calling `test` with a string parameter

Comment: Then there's your answer. DOM "id" property values are strings.

Comment: The compiler enforces the type when it compiles the code to JavaScript, but it doesn't prevent (i.e. doesn't generate code that would prevent) passing whatever type variables to the function during runtime.

Comment: @JJJ Thanks. That's a good explanation. I missed that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've used the term "hard typed" which is just *not a thing* in TypeScript. TypeScript does not automatically convert *runtime* values; if you have JavaScript code and call TypeScript code with incorrectly typed arguments, there is no conversion taking place to "fix" that.

Remember: TypeScript and JavaScript **have the same runtime semantics**. Any question you have about why `===` has some runtime result in TypeScript is exactly the same as the JavaScript question (which has been asked hundreds of times on StackOverflow already so I won't go into that).

Comment: I do not like the explanation because it collides with my laziness and being used to C#. Reluctantly, I accept the answer and +1 you. Also, I'm a bit ashamed for not seeing it myself. :)